# Rsync: Skip files that are not present locally?

Tags: rsync

```
+------+-----+------+
|Local |     |Remote|
+------+-----+------+
|file01| <-  |file01|
+------+-----+------+
|-     |     |file02|
+------+-----+------+
|file03| <-  |file03|
+------+-----+------+
|-     |     |file04|
+------+-----+------+
|-     |     |file09|
+------+-----+------+
|file10| <-  |file10|
+------+-----+------+
|file11| <-  |file11|
+------+-----+------+
|file12|     |      |
+------+-----+------+
```

I am using `rsync` and after skimming over the man pages, I couldn't find a combination, where I can sync only files that are present **LOCAL** to be updated by **REMOTE** files.

Thus, I want to update only the files `file01, file03, file10, and file11` and want to skip all other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this option:

```
        --existing              skip creating new files on receiver
```